# Index out of bounds when subtracting X

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the rectangular area of a trip, more context can be found here[image]
[image]

The error I get in the code below is:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1    at Main.main(Main.java:50)"

The fix might be obvious but I simply don't get it, if this code can compile and it gives a good output, do you guys have any idea on how to get the rectangular area calculated automatically and not do it manually, just a tip or an idea, not the whole code.

```
public class Main extends JPanel{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line = " F 6 R 1 F 4 RFF 2 LFF 1 LFFFR 1 F 2 R 1 F 5 ";
    String pattern = "[RLF ]+[1-9]{1}";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

    List<String> operations = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("found this "+ m.group());
        operations.add(m.group());
    }

    String[][] arrays = new String[1000][1000];
    int x = 500;
    int y = 500;
    arrays[x][y] = "1";

    int k = 1;
    for(String operation : operations){
        int op = Integer.parseInt(operation.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
        String directions = operation.replaceAll("[0-9]{1}", "");
        char[] directionsArray = directions.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<op; i++){
            for( int j = 0; i<directionsArray.length; j++){
                if(directionsArray[j] != ' '){
                    if (directionsArray[j] == 'R'){
                        k =+ 1;
                        if(k > 4) k = 1;
                    }else if (directionsArray[j] == 'L'){
                        k =- 1;
                        if(k < 1) k = 4;
                    }else if (directionsArray[j] == 'F'){
                        if (k == 1) {
                            x =- 1;
                            arrays[x][y] = "1";
                        }else if (k == 2){
                            y =+ 1;
                            arrays[x][y] = "1";
                        }else if(k == 3){
                            x =+ 1;
                            arrays[x][y] = "1";
                        }else if(k == 4){
                            y =-1;
                            arrays[x][y] = "1";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i =0; i<arrays.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; i<arrays.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning `y` to -1 (Java parses `y =-1;` as `y = -1;`) then using it as an index on the next line. You probably meant to decrement `y` with `y -= 1;` instead. (There are several spots where this is done to both the `x` and `y` variables.)

Comment: same for all other increments and decrements in the code... @clickclack consider using increment and decrement operators instead (like `k++` and `k--` for example)